# Overriding methods by changing typedef in ancestor - possible?

Tags: c++, typedef

I am trying to base my application on callbacks. The issue that bothers me the most is that I have to specify what arguments does the lambda function take. My base class that all others extend does specify two basic types. It looks like this:

```
class Callback
{
    typedef function<void()> Function;
    typedef vector< pair<string, vector<Function>> > CallbackContainer;

public:
    void callback(string); // both types are used
```

Is it possible to change the arguments of the lambda function (the `Function` type) just by overriding the type in classes extending this one? Or does the code in the `callback` method use the original types? If so, can I force the usage of new types without copying and pasting the code? Just to fulfill the DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are not virtual; you cannot "override" them in a derived class.

From my somewhat limited understanding of what you're trying to do, I think you should make `Callback` a template. Something like this:

```
template<typename ArgType>
class Callback
{
    typedef function<void(ArgType)> Function;
    typedef vector< pair<string, vector<Function>> > CallbackContainer;

public:
    void callback(string); // both types are used
```

This works only for functions that take exactly one argument, of course. Making it more general in current-day C++ is far from trivial; in C++0x it gets a little bit easier with variadic templates.

Maybe you could have a look at Boost, though. There's a good chance that you can use something that is already in there, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Also thanks for mentioning variadic templates, I had no idea such a thing would be possible in C++.